# Mocking data and Calling action from container

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I'm having issues making a Unit Testing because I have this code `helperController` Controller:

```
public static function applyDiscount(array $params, MoneyParser $moneyParser): Money
{
    $discount = Money::BRL(0);
    switch ($params['typeOf']) {
        case 'above_value':
            $amount = $params['value']->subtract($params['value']->multiply(0.85));
            $discount = $discount->add($amount);
            break;
        case 'above_quantity':
            $subtractedQuantity = intval(round($params['quantity'] / 3));
            $value = $params['value']->multiply($subtractedQuantity);
            $discount = $discount->add($value);
            break;
        case 'same_category':
            $lowestVal = 0;
            foreach ($params['cart'] as $item) {
                if (empty($lowestVal)) {
                    $lowestVal = $item['unitPrice'];
                } elseif ($item['unitPrice'] < $lowestVal) {
                    $lowestVal = $item['unitPrice'];
                }
            }
            $valueOf = floatval($lowestVal) * 0.40;
            $rounded = floor($valueOf * 100) / 100;
            $unitPrice = $moneyParser->parse(strval($rounded), 'BRL');
            $discount = $discount->add($unitPrice);
            break;
        case 'for_employees':
            $amount = $params['value']->subtract($params['value']->multiply(0.80));
            $discount = $discount->add($amount);
            break;
        case 'for_newones':
            $amount = $moneyParser->parse('25', 'BRL');
            $discount = $discount->add($amount);
            break;
    }

    return $discount;
}
```

And I'm trying to mock the data to test it, for example, in the first case I'm trying to do this:

```
public function testApplyDiscountAboveValue(): void
{
    $params = [
        'typeOf' => 'above_value',
        'value' => Money::BRL('3001'),
    ];

    $money = app(MoneyParser::class);

    $currency = app(Currency::class, ['code' => 'BRL']);

    $moneyValue = app(Money::class, [ 
        'amount' => 3001,
        'currency' => $currency
    ]);

    $discount = app(Money::class, [
        'amount' => 450,
        'currency' => $currency
    ]);

    $mock = Mockery::mock($moneyValue);

    $mock->shouldReceive('multiply')
        ->with(0.85)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('2550'));

    $mock->shouldReceive('subtract')
        ->with(Money::BRL('2550'))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('450'));

    $mock->shouldReceive('add')
        ->with(Money::BRL('450'))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('450'));

    $response = app(HelperDiscountController::class)->applyDiscount($params, $money);
    $this->assertEquals($discount, $response);
}
```

When I execute the phpunit my result is this:

> 1. App\Http\Controllers\HelperDiscountControllerTest::testApplyDiscountAboveValue
>    Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method multiply(0.85) from Mockery_0_Money_Money_Money_Money should be called
>    exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

I'm trying to understand what I am doing wrong. Did I have all the necessary adaptations to test my code at least for the first case?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you have a static method in a controller, you are doing something wrong, it should be a non-static method, like this:

```php
public function applyDiscount(array $params, MoneyParser $moneyParser): Money
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Second, if the method `applyDiscount` is a helper method inside a controller or a parent controller, I would not pass an `array $params`, but directly a `Request $request` and use that object, because the `array` could have missing indexes and you should constantly validate them, with a `Request` object you can directly do `$request->has('param')` or do `$request->input('param')` (and pass a second parameter if you want a default value different from `null` if `param` is not present on the request as a parameter).

I do see that, for example, `$params['value']` is an object, because you are doing operations on it, so if `$params` is not a parameter (you will never get an object from a `Request` as a parameter) then rename the variable to something else that truly repesent what it has, or at least, pass the content as separte method's parameters instead of an `array` of objects or similar.

---

Third, now onto the test. `$response = app(HelperDiscountController::class)->applyDiscount($params, $money);` will never work (get the `mock`), because you are never passing that mock into the Service Cointaner or into an instance as a dependency, you are creating the mock and not using it anywhere.

The code is a little bit confusing for me right now, but what you should have is something like this:

#### Controller

```php
public function applyDiscount(Request $request, ): Money
{
    // Validate or use a Form Request
    // Do anything else you would need to

    $result = $this->helperMethod(... needed params);

    // Either return the result or process more stuff and return something if needed
    return $result;
}
```

#### Test

```php
public function testApplyDiscountAboveValue(): void
{
    // When you need to mock something, you do it this way
    $mock = $this->mock(WhateverClass::class);

    $mock->shouldReceive('multiply')
        ->with(0.85)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('2550'));

    $mock->shouldReceive('subtract')
        ->with(Money::BRL('2550'))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('450'));

    $mock->shouldReceive('add')
        ->with(Money::BRL('450'))
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(Money::BRL('450'));

    $response = $this->post(
        'your/url/to/the/controller/endpoint',
        [
            'param1' => 'data1',
            'paramN' => 'dataN',
        ],
    );

    $this->assertEquals($discount, $response);
}
```

See that:

- When you use `$this->mock(Class)`, it is internally binding that class resolution (when you do `app(class)` or `resolve(class)` or you let Laravel use Dependency Injection), it will return that mock
- I am calling an endpoint using `$this->post(url, data)`, you can use any HTTP method, but must match the route (that is how you test routes)
- You need to share more info becausue it is very confusing (for me) what you are trying to test
- Check my StackOverflow profile, I have some links in my profile about testing, it will help you a lot
- Check the documentation as it is already explained in there most of the things you are trying to do

  - [HTTP test](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests)
  - [Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-objects)
  - [Automatic Resolving/Dependency Injection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#resolving)

Comment: applyDiscount would be a method in static class in controller because I wanted another class just to control how my discount is applyed in another Controller that I've called CartsController, so this is why $params is not aways the same, and moneyParser would be something that I don't wanna create another injection this is why I bring it from CartsController... thx although :)

Comment: @julio_pin oh, okay, in that case you should have a new class in a new folder, for example `Domain`, and have that logic there then, in whatever controller/job/listener/console command you need that code, just access it statically or use a Facade to reference that class, but you do not create a static method and "share it" between controllers or other classes, that is not correct on the Laravel framework